# Study long term properties of two polymers

Tags: polymers, materials

This is a material-science question, and I didn't know where else to put it.

I (and two others) are mechanical engineering students and are starting a bachelor's thesis which involves some material science. We are to study two polymers, PEEK along with an unknown elastomer.

We are doing the simulation using the software ANSYS, and there are different models of e.g. creep one can choose from, and they need some constants that describes the properties. We're about to do some tensile-tests to investigate the basic properties of these materials. However I believe we also need data about the long-term properties of these materials, which we'll have to get from previous studies. Can anyone point us in the right direction where we could find the relevant studies? We're not that familiar with searching for literature.
I'm about to dive down into textbooks about this, and if anyone has any advice that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A good start would be to know what the unknown elastomer is.